# Determine the short exact sequences of Z-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $p ∈ \mathbb N$ be prime. Determine the (isomorphism classes of) short exact sequences of $\mathbb Z$-modules that are of type

$$0\xrightarrow[]{}\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\xrightarrow[]{}M\xrightarrow[]{}\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\xrightarrow[]{}0.$$

An obvious solution is $M=\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\bigoplus \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$. But I don't know how to proceed after this. I think some properties of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ will be used.

It's an exercise in Bosch, *Commutative algebra and algebraic geometry*.

Comment: This follows from $H^2(\Bbb Z/p,\Bbb Z/p))\cong \Bbb Z/p$, which is proved here. So there are $p$ inequivalent extensions.

Comment: There is a completely elementary way to solve this. By classification theorem of finite abelian groups, $M$ can only be $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^2$ in which case the exact sequences are over the finite field $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, hence must split. Or $M\simeq\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$, then there are $p-1$ isomorphism classes, as $M$ contains only $1$ subgroups of order $p$ and each identity map on it can be extended to $p-1$ automorphisms of $M$ itself.